# JavaFX 3D API does not work on all Android deivces

Tags: javafx, 3d, gluon, javafxports

Hi I have been compiling a JavaFX app for Android using the JavaFXPorts plugin for a while.  I have managed to resolve all the dependencies and compiled into an APK.  This APK will install on Android devices but doesn't work on all of them.  I have tried it on a number of devices, those that support 3D display fine but those that don't just show a black screen.

I have tried testing a HelloWorld app on a number of Android devices.  It works on all of my devices with just a HelloWorld label on the screen but as soon as I add a sphere into the scene it just displays a black screen on some devices (some devices work and some don't).  I have searched on the internet and suggestions indicate that this may be a memory issue but I cannot get around it.

Comment: You can ask check for [JavaFX features](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/ConditionalFeature.html#SCENE3D), such as 3D, by [asking the platform what is supported](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#isSupported(javafx.application.ConditionalFeature)) and code your app accordingly (if it returns the correct value on query).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  I have tried displaying Platform.isSupported(ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D) and it shows true but it still stops working when Shape3D objects are added to the Scene